# Fix our Cisco switch overwhelmed by console logging

Tags: cisco, cisco-ios, cisco-catalyst, cisco-commands, troubleshooting

I have a setup with dual redundant Cisco catalyst 4506-E using the WS-X45-SUP8L-E supervisor engine and two 48-port switches below it.

- My task is to access and modify the switch configuration.
- Access shall be accomplished locally only, through console port using
  serial cable and user/pass combo.
- When connecting to the console port I notice that synchronous
  terminal mode has not been enabled, and logging to console has been
  set up.
- The switch is in production and should not be power cycled unless
  absolutely neccessary.
- I can't type or paste in the username because console logging blocks
  the input.
- Can't authenticate -> Can't access config mode -> Can't turn off logging temporarily to login.

Any suggestions on how to access this switch?

Comment: Is this a homework question?

Comment: It's funny how it's "redundant", but you can't plan a service window to fix the problem? I've never seen a system so important, combined with the fact it's redundant, that cannot be put into maintenance.

Comment: To follow up on Cown comment. If a system is redundant you *should* put it down from time to time to ensure the redundancy works as expected. If you don't, the day you need it, it will not work.

Comment: @Cown: Not homework. Work-work and I just started with this setup this morning. Absolutely agree, but my instructions were clearly stated beforehand: I was not allowed to power down the device, and the only configured auth method was user/pass combo.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I have a setup with dual redundant Cisco catalyst 4506-E using the WS-X45-SUP8L-E supervisor engine and two 48-port switches below it.
>
> - My task is to access and modify the switch configuration.
> - Access shall be accomplished locally only, through console port using serial cable and user/pass combo.

The notion that "thou shalt not use ssh / telnet / SNMP to fix this problem" is broken.  Use what you can to fix it.  Yes, console logging at a lower baud rate relative to a faster stream of incoming console syslog messages is a pain; however you can't change what's already happened.

If nobody set up SNMP / telnet / ssh authentication methods *and* you can't change the environment which is generating so many logs, the right answer to take to your management is: "Sorry but this service was not set up in a maintainable manner.  We have to take an outage to fix it."

Then fix what you know is wrong:

- Common practice is to disable console logging completely with `no logging console`.  I use `no logging console guaranteed`, but that's a personal preference.
- Set up SNMP RO / SNMP RW communities with the right ACLs if not already in place
- Set up SSH access
- It sounds like there is a lack of confidence in the redundancy provided by this service.  During your outage window, demonstrate expected outage times when you drop power on the active supervisor (do this at least 3 to 5 times so you know how repeatable it is).  If the redundancy performance is not what you want, sometimes you can change timers or the protocol to get what you want.

Our community is here to help if you have questions about how to improve failover performance, or configuring the items above.

Comment: Thank you for a great answer. I ultimately ended up power cycling the active chassis and authenticating before syslog output had started streaming too frequently to block my input. After that I did no logging console, and to be sure also  activated logging synchronous. Set up SSH and spent half the work day doing what I came to do.

Comment: FYI, there is no need to "race login" against the logging flood.  Tell the router to ignore the default configuration; then edit it / save. To do so, [go into rommon mode](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/switches/catalyst-4000-series-switches/24061-149.html#reboot), then [set your `confreg`](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/routers/10000-series-routers/50421-config-register-use.html#anc13) to [0x2142](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/routers/10000-series-routers/50421-config-register-use.html).  You could also just unplug the input cables if there aren't a bunch.